# Filter column pairs given a numeric threshold from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following DataFrame in which I need to filter rows given a pair of IDs from two different columns by selecting a pair that has the highest numeric value from a third column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['11x', '12x', 5.5, 'other_1'], 
    ['11x', '12x', 3.5, 'other_2'],
    ['10x', '9x', 1.5, 'other_1'],
    ['10x', '9x', 3.5, 'other_2'],
    ['1x', '1x', 3.5, 'other_x'],
]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id1', 'id2', 'to_filter_on', 'other_data']) 

df.head()


# output of head
"""
    id1     id2     to_filter_on    other_data
0   11x     12x     5.5     other_1
1   11x     12x     3.5     other_2
2   10x     9x      1.5     other_1
3   10x     9x      3.5     other_2
4   1x      2x      3.5     other_x
"""
```

Given the pairs of ID fields (id1 and id2) I want to only select a pair where the threshold from the column `to_filter_on` is the highest. In a sense, I need a following DataFrame given the one above:

```
"""
    id1     id2     to_filter_on    other_data
0   11x     12x     5.5     other_1
1   10x     9x      3.5     other_2
2   1x      2x      3.5     other_x
"""
```

Notice that the ID pair "11x and 12x" with lower value in `to_filter_on` was removed, same for pair of "10x and 9x".

Any pointers and help are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `idxmax` to get the indices of the highest "to_filter_on" value, then use that to index `df`:

```
df.iloc[df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'], sort=False)['to_filter_on'].idxmax()]

   id1  id2  to_filter_on other_data
0  11x  12x           5.5    other_1
3  10x   9x           3.5    other_2
4   1x   1x           3.5    other_x
```

Alternatively, avoid the `groupby` by sorting and dropping duplicates:

```
(df.sort_values(['id1', 'id2', 'to_filter_on'])
   .drop_duplicates(['id1', 'id2'], keep='last')
   .sort_index())

   id1  id2  to_filter_on other_data
0  11x  12x           5.5    other_1
3  10x   9x           3.5    other_2
4   1x   1x           3.5    other_x
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to retain *all* rows with the same (max) values of `to_filter_on`:

```
s = df.groupby(['id1','id2'])['to_filter_on'].transform('max')
df[df.to_filter_on.eq(s)]
```

gives:

```
    id1     id2     to_filter_on    other_data
0   11x     12x     5.5             other_1
3   10x     9x      3.5             other_2
4   1x      1x      3.5             other_x
```